# JSON different objects in an array

Tags: java, json, gson

At the moment i'm trying to understand json and how it works.
But i have a problem with an **array of objects**.
**all objects** in the array have a **key** called "value" (i know it's weird, it's not my code) what also is an **object**.
And now to the problem: This object called "value" has always different key-values.
So i dont now how i can parse the json code to java object code, when it differ, every time.

Here some examples:

First object of the array:

```
 "value":
 {
   "local":
   [
     "English", "Deutsch", Espanol"
   ],
  "english":
   [ 
     "English", "Deutsch", Espanol"
   ],
 },
```

Second object(now a string, not object) of the array:

```
"value" : "",
```

Third object of the array:

```
"value" : {},
```

...

Maybe I'm doing the parsing wrong.
First I have created the beans classes in java for the json code and then I'm using the automatic parser of google. (gson)
It works when only one of the examples above is inside the json code. (it should not differ, like changing from string to object...)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Output output = gson.fromJson(json, Output.class);
```

Output is the main class for the json stuff.

I have found out that maybe while parsing I could check a value called "id" first, and from that I could create another beans class with the right variables ...

Thats the code i need to parse to java objects and how do you do that??
The problem is the key called "value", because its always different.
With my method of using the google parser "gson" it wont work, because i'm getting exception that its an string but i was waiting for an object...

```
{
 "status":"success",
 "data":{
 "panel":{
 "title":{
 "label":{ "local":"Tote Selection", "english":"Tote Selection" },
 "image":"public/img/pick.jpg", "type":"default"
 },
 "isFirst":false, // currently not used
 "isLast":false, // currently not used
 "ownCount":0, // currently not used
 "panelsCount":0, // currently not used
 "elements":[
 {
 "type":"text",
 "id":"1", "value":{ "local":"Scan next order tote", 
 "english":"Scan next order tote" },
 "label":{ "local":"", "english":"" }, "color":"000000", 
 "fontsize":18, "fontstyle":"flat", "alignment":"left",
 "rows":"undefined", "bgcolor":"", "isFocus":false
 },
 {
 "type":"text",
 "id":"4", "value":{ "local":"Scan tote: ", "english":"Scan tote: " },
 "label":{ "local":"", "english":"" }, "color":"000000", "fontsize":20, 
 "fontstyle":"strong", "alignment":"left", "rows":"undefined", 
 "bgcolor":"", "isFocus":false
 },
 {
 "type":"input",
 "id":"6", "value":"", "label":{ "local":"", "english":"" },
 "color":"000000", "fontsize":24, "fontstyle":"flat", "alignment":"left",
 "rows":"undefined", "isFocus":true
 },
 {
 "type":"button",
 "id":"1", "value":{ "local":"", "english":"" },
 "label":{ "local":"Menu", "english":"Menu" }, "color":"000000", 
 "fontsize":14, "fontstyle":"strong", "alignment":"left",
 "rows":"undefined", "isFocus":false
 },
 {
 "type":"button",
 "id":"4", "value":{ "local":"", "english":"" },
 "label":{ "local":"Enter", "english":"Enter" }, "color":"000000", 
 "fontsize":14, "fontstyle":"strong", "alignment":"right",18
 "rows":"undefined", "isFocus":false
 }
 ]
 },
 "authToken":"0fdd440a-619f-4936-ab74-d189accb5bd9",
 "routing":{
 "controller":"panel",
 "action":"process",
 "workflowId":"singlepicking",
 "taskId":"orderSelection"
 }
 }
 }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: so what is the requirement, is it to retrieve the values from JSON Array?? if yes just use a for loop.

Comment: yes all values of the array and his objects, strings ....

Comment: what do you mean with just use a for loop. I mean i cant do that if gson is parsing the code for me.

Comment: I have posted the code for simple json array dont know it will work for gson or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood ur question properly u can retrieve the values of the JSONArray as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < JArray.length(); i++) {
          print(JArray.getJSONObject(i).tostring())
        }
```

So if i am right u are getting the JSON from a String First?? so please try below first store the String in JSONObject as     `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);//str is the string that u are getting`

to get the valueenglish   that are in data-panel-tittle-label is

```
String englishinLable=obj .getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("panel").getJSONObject("title").getJSONObject("label").optString("english")
```

Comment: and the rest? its not only an array, look at the code i have posted now.

Comment: So if i am right u are getting the JSON from a String First??

Comment: ok i will try your code. It looks good, but i can only try it in 5 hours or so. If it then work i will accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

it looks a little bit different but your answer helped me! Thx

```
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject obj = parser.parse(br).getAsJsonObject();

        //now getting all the  json values
        String status = obj.get("status").getAsString();
        JsonObject data = obj.getAsJsonObject("data");

        String authToken = data.get("authToken").getAsString();
        JsonObject routing = data.getAsJsonObject("routing");
        String controller = routing.get("controller").getAsString();
        String action = routing.get("action").getAsString();
        String workflowId = routing.get("taskId").getAsString();
```